# Extracting coordinates of line feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, vector, coordinates, features

I need to get the x and y or lat and lon for a line feature in order to create a unique `"ID"` for a project I am working on.

I know a line feature has more than one lat and lon but I just need the first one to get my job done. I have tried creating a new column and then using `$y` and `$x` but that doesn't work for line feature.

Is there another way to extract the points of a line feature?

Comment: So do you have a line feature but its in the wrong place? Or is it in the right place and you just want to get the coordinates out - which isn't georeferencing....

Comment: I want to get the coordinates of the line feature. What ever that process is called

Comment: So the right place and you just want to get the coordinates out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the expression editor, `$x_at(0)` will get the x coordinate of the first (0-th) point of line features. `$y_at(0)` gets the y coordinate.

You can then add these to a new column like you tried with `$x` (which only works for point geometry)

Comment: Thank you ! what would you call this process if its not georeferencing

Comment: I'd call it "finding the coordinates of...". Georeferencing is setting the coordinates of a feature to the right values - ie making it correctly "referenced" geographically.  Its what you do when you have an aerial photograph and need to tell your GIS where the corners are.

Comment: Maybe geopositioning or geolocating https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geopositioning or even geotagging https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geotagging.